# Image captured and then deleted from gallery. Can it be recovered and get into wrong hands?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, photos, gallery, images

I have captured a photo with my samsung galaxy ace nxt phone, which has android os v4.4.2 kitkat. Then I have deleted it from my gallery. I haven't uploaded it anywhere, nor shared it anywhere else. What I want to know is - can the photo can be recovered? I don't want it to recover for myself, but don't want it to get into wrong hands if someone has full access to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any ordinary deleted data can be restored, **BUT...**

... many programs delete data like this: They tell the hard drive (flasdrive, etc.) that the deleted area can be overwritten. Aslong you dont fill your diskspace, you can recover the deleted files full or partial.

What you can do against:

Simply use your smartphone, data will be added, deleted, modified when you do something with it.

Fill your diskspace: Well it sounds nonsense, but it works. Simply move files on your sdcard, or internal storage and fill the disk space, than delete them. The old data is finally gone.

Greetings,
Fischmaster

Comment: You forgot one thing: there do exist some softwares that, instead of telling the FS to mark a "deleted" file space as usable, overwrite the same portion of storage with junk instead, thereby making the recovering operation extremely difficult or impossible.

Comment: Yes, there simply stuff like writing zero's over.

Comment: Writing just zeroes over has been proved to be insufficient in some circumstances, so it's generally better to overwrite with random data, or by performing more than one operation.

Comment: Yes, agree. Havent seen vor used so many.